# How to display sku on product page not description page in shopify

Tags: shopify

Hie

I have to display Stock Keeping Unit on product page not description page. Actually i have a page in which firstly i display all the products and on the click of product it goes to product description page. Now on first page i have to display Stock Keeping Unit.

Please help me to get out from this trouble.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 2):

SKUs are specific to a product's variants, not the product object itself. Within a product loop, you could use something like `{{ product.variants.first.sku }}` or within a variant loop you could just use `{{ variant.sku }}`

The following would work on your shop (collection) page -

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
    <a href="{{ product.url }}" class="product">

        <h2>{{ product.title }}</h2>
        <span class="sku">{{ product.variants.first.sku }}</span>

    </a>
{% endfor %}
```